# How do I use external routes in my routes index file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `users.js` and a `index.js` file.

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {catchErrors} = require('../handlers/errorHandlers');

const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

router.post('login/', catchErrors(authController.login));

module.exports.router = router;
```

**index.js**

```
// Route handlers
let userRouter = require('./users');

router.use('/user', userRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

I tried this and it's not working. I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your `users.js` file you're exporting an object with the property `router` (`module.exports.router = router`) which would look like..

```
module.exports = {
  router: router
}
```

and in your index you're importing the object from `users.js` but not accessing the router when passing it to `router.use(...)`.

You should pass the router in your `index.js` file

#### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// You can access the router on the require
const userRouter = require('./users').router;
router.use('/user', userRouter);

// Or on the object after the require
const userRouter = require('./users');
router.use('/user', userRouter.router);
```